# How do I share an ASP.NET web forms site through visual studio online or azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms, azure-devops

Please bear with me as I've never used .NET to do team development but how do I share the code for an ASP.NET web forms site (not MVC or web forms application) through visual studio online?  I've figured it out how to do it through a web forms application but I'm not familiar with how to code in a web forms application, and I can't put a web forms site into the team explorer solutions because it's not a project.  With this assignment we are also tasked to use azure for deployment of the website and hosting databases.  Any information with how to regulate team development of a web forms site would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Sites have been deprecated since 2010. You should upgrade to a Web application. The technology is the same. Your only difference is that your code behind is all compiled into the same DLL so your pages need unique names so that they do not collide.

Once you have upgraded your automated build woul create the necessary output.